# Payload ideas for an 1U CubeSat

Tags: satellites

I don't know if this is the relevant site for such questions, but I am asking it anyway.

Our school has taken up a project on launching a **CubeSat** and I am part of the 45 contributing students. We are supposed to research on a suitable payload for the CubeSat.

We were thinking of some Remote Sensing or Earth Observational applications in a coastal area **(like in our city)**. I have looked up on the internet for possible ideas (like measuring ground vertical displacement using InSar technology?) but I am not sure if those applications are suitable for an **1U** CubeSat.

Can someone suggest some ideas ?

**Info. about the Sat. :**

**Dimensions:** 10cm * 10cm * 10cm

**Weight:** ~ 1.33 kg

**To be launched in the LEO Orbit between 350 to 455 km range**

Comment: I love this question, but you're likely to get some hate on here for it because there isn't a strictly correct answer, and this community doesn't tend to treat brainstorming-type questions without definite answers very well

Comment: @Tal It's also far too concrete and physical for the mathematicians here.

Comment: Can't do an answer, but here are some comments. The sort of remote sensing you're thinking of is too difficult  for a 1U. For one thing, you need good attitude control. That's very hard in a 1U, even if you're an expert with lots of experience. And then, you need an instrument. The kind of sophistication you imagine takes more resources than a 1U has, but your attitude control system has already taken everything.

Comment: So, try to find something you can do with no attitude stabilization, or perhaps something crude like a controlled Thomson spin.

Comment: You might actually get some really good answers from [Worldbuilding SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/). They're ostensibly for writers building imaginary worlds, but they might have fun with this one

Comment: With half a kg of CsI, you can detect the brighter gamma ray bursts. You can't compete with the more sophisticated detectors on Swift and Fermi, but "80% of life is showing up": there are bursts they miss because they're on the wrong side of the Earth or pointed in the wrong direction. LIGO might detect a big kilonova and you might get the only gamma ray light curve. It's a bit unlikely, though. While you're waiting, you could monitor background radiation in your orbit. Extra credit for including a diode detector sensitive to particles but not gammas, so you can tell the difference.

Comment: Or do a radio pollution experiment: every few minutes, record a summary of what a broadband radio receiver picks up, Make a map of Earth showing where the most radio energy is radiated.

Comment: Or monitor plasma in your orbit. A Langmuir probe is a small, low resource instrument.

Comment: Thanks for your advice !!

Comment: @JohnDoty - "Extra credit for including a diode detector sensitive to particles but not gammas, so you can tell the difference" -- how about a scintillator ?

Comment: A scintillator is what you make using half a kg of CsI. I suppose you could use a *plastic* scintillator for particles, but a diode is easier, I think.

Comment: And why is this question closed? This is about coming up with a real experiment, not just making marks on a whiteboard.

Comment: @JohnDoty - while I voted to reopen, an issue is that there is not a 'correct' answer. But experimental physics is not valued much here and it is a nice question to ponder.

Comment: This might be a better question for [Space.SE];  if it doesn't get re-opened here (or even if it does?) you might try asking it over there instead.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I don't think so. The Space Exploration group doesn't really cover the scientific aspect.